# LINQ GroupBy x where there is more then one x and y is unique

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

Let there be an objects like so:

```
class foo
{
    public String x{ get; set; }
    public String y{ get; set; }
}

var bar = new List<foo> {
 new foo{ x= "u", y= "w"},
 new foo{ x= "s", y= "q"},
 new foo{ x= "u", y= "r" },
 new foo{ x= "1", y= "0" },
 new foo{ x= "1", y= "0" },
};
```

I would like group these where x is the same but y is different.

This will get me the foos where x is the same and there is more then one.

```
 bar.GroupBy(x => x.x).Where(x => x.Count() > 1).ToList();
```

Here is what I get:

```
foo{ x= "u", y= "w"}
foo{ x= "u", y= "r" }
foo{ x= "1", y= "0" }
foo{ x= "1", y= "0" }
```

Here is what I want to get:

```
foo{ x= "u", y= "w"}
foo{ x= "u", y= "r" }
```

So how do I filter out the ones where y is the same?

**UPDATE**

With 3,999,996 objects in bar all three of these work correctly.

```
bar.GroupBy(f => f.x).Where(a => a.Select(f => f.y).Distinct().Skip(1).Any()).ToList(); // Elapsed ms = 702,715,779,666 AVG = 715
bar.GroupBy(f => f.x).Where(a => a.Count() > 1 && a.Any(b => b.y!= a.First().y)).ToList(); // Elapsed ms = 753,701,728,749 AVG = 732
bar.GroupBy(f => f.x).Where(a => a.Skip(1).Any() && a.Any(b => b.y!= a.First().y)).ToList(); //  Elapsed ms = 734,751,758,745 AVG = 747
```

Comment: Do a [`Distinct`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.distinct.aspx) on `y`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nearly there!

```
bar.GroupBy(f => f.x)
   .Where(g => g.Select(f => f.y).Distinct().Skip(1).Any())
   .ToList();
```

`g.Select(f => f.y).Distinct().Count()` says "get all the `y` values from the `foo`s in the group, throw away any duplicates, and *then* count them".

**Edit**: `.Skip(1).Any()` is better than `.Count() > 1` because it stops looking as soon as it finds a second item, ratehr than finding a million and then going `a million > 1`. Usually I get that right first time...

(Note that your result isn't a list of `foo`s, it's a list of groups of `foo`s where each group has a constant `x`.)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
bar
  .GroupBy(a => a.x)
  .Where(a => a.Count() > 1 && a.Any(b=>b.y != a.First().y))
  .ToList();
```

Comment: Your solution works however Rawling's just a little faster. On average 30 ms.